# Operate RDD in SPARK, merge lines into block by line separator

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a copy of RDD data from the following file, I want to merge lines based on the line separator, so that I can get RDD[Person].

`case class Person(id: String, name: String, job: String)`

```
--------------
id : 1
name : amy
job : teacher
--------------
id : 2
name : bob
job : nurse
--------------
id : 3
name : charlie
job : policeman
--------------
```

Please note that the data file is huge, which cannot fit into memory, so you cannot do something like

```
val lines = sc.textFile("/path/to/file")
val person = lines.collect...
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

If your text file has the format you explain, you could implement a custom datasource. See example [here](https://github.com/jorgeglezlopez/spark-arff-data-source)

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

```
val linesRdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/file")
val lineSeparator = "--------------"
var lastSeparatorIndex = 0

val personLinesRdd: RDD[String] = linesRdd
  .zipWithIndex
  .map{ case(line, index) =>
    if(line == lineSeparator) lastSeparatorIndex = index
    (line, lastSeparatorIndex)
  }

val personSlicesRdd: RDD[Seq[String] = personLinesRdd
  .groupBy{case (index, _) => index}
  .map{ case (_, lines) => lines.toSeq.map { case (line, _) => line }}
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)

val persons: RDD[Person] = personSlicesRdd.map(toPerson(_))
```